# jQuery selector to select data-x attributes but to exclude those under certain .class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to select all custom data-x under `.classA`, `.classC`, `.classD`, and `classF` but not `.classB` and `.classE` elements. I am using `$('[data-x'])`, but it picks up all.

```js
const me = $('.container');
console.log($('[data-x]', me));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='container'>
  <div class='classA' data-x='1'>Class A</div>
  <div class='classB' data-x='2'>Class B</div>
  <div class='classC' data-x='3'>Class C</div>
  <div class='classD' data-x='4'>Class D</div>
  <div class='classE' data-x='5'>Class E</div>
  <div class='classF' data-x='6'>Class F</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there are multiple classes, you can use `filter`:

```js
const arr = ["classB", "classE"];

var all = $('[data-x]').filter((ind, el) => !arr.includes(el.classList[0]));
all.css({ backgroundColor: 'yellow' });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='container'>
  <div class='classA' data-x='1'>Class A</div>
  <div class='classB' data-x='2'>Class B</div>
  <div class='classC' data-x='3'>Class C</div>
  <div class='classD' data-x='4'>Class D</div>
  <div class='classE' data-x='5'>Class E</div>
  <div class='classF' data-x='6'>Class F</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a couple of `:not`s:

```js
const elms = $('.container > div:not(.classB):not(.classE)')
  .css({ backgroundColor: 'yellow' });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='container'>
  <div class='classA' data-x='1'>Class A</div>
  <div class='classB' data-x='2'>Class B</div>
  <div class='classC' data-x='3'>Class C</div>
  <div class='classD' data-x='4'>Class C</div>
  <div class='classE' data-x='5'>Class C</div>
  <div class='classF' data-x='6'>Class C</div>
</div>
```